# Downloading the Panama Papers

Tags: data-request, finance, nlp

I wonder where the [Panama Papers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panama_Papers) can be downloaded. I have looked around, I couldn't find them.

Where can I find them?

What is the legality, and sensibility of requesting and downloading leaked data? Is now that it's leaked it's in the public domain?

**Bounty edit:** Summarise all current sources of data, and explain what's in them, what format the data is, etc.

Comment: Here you go............ http://www.thereportertimes.com/panama-papers-icij-offshore-leaks-database-documents/23489/ Scroll down the page a bit

Comment: See https://github.com/amaboura/panama-papers-dataset-2016

Comment: You could just link the archive.org site: https://archive.org/download/OffshoreLeaksDatabase

Comment: Wikileaks has an unconfirmed copy and may release the full data before "early May", which is slated by SZ - https://twitter.com/wikileaks/status/716772373408718849

Comment: @5chdn is correct. Neither the full 'leak' of papers nor an index of entities are available. Several answers and comments here mistake the [Offshore Leaks](https://offshoreleaks.icij.org/about/download) files for the Panama Papers.

Comment: thanks for the info. can you please add this as a comment underneath the answer you agree with? this seems more like a comment than an answer...unless you want to add more to it.

Comment: @albert: Arthur Morris hasn't yet enough reputation to comment everywhere ... but a moderator can turn this answer into a comment.

Comment: I'm not sure I would consider the Panama Papers Open Data. Indeed there are plenty of personal data in there. And even if it is good journalism material, there is a reason why it has not leaked yet and why the ICIJ hasn't released it. I have no opinion on what can be done with it, it's just I don't think that would be Open Data :)

Comment: lol....good point. hopefully one will come and do this soon.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4066)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Panama Papers database has just been published at this link
https://www.occrp.org/en/panamapapers/database.html

> This ICIJ database contains information on almost 320,000 offshore entities that are part of the Panama Papers and the Offshore Leaks investigations. The data covers nearly 40 years up to the end of 2015 and links to people and companies in more than 200 countries and territories.

Comment: You're fast! Good job.

Answer (score 14):

#### No leak

The *Panama Papers* were not leaked at all. They were handed over to a [German media company](http://panamapapers.sueddeutsche.de/articles/56febff0a1bb8d3c3495adf4/) which probably [paid a good price](http://www.nachdenkseiten.de/?p=32753) ([translation/summary here](https://nettime.org/Lists-Archives/nettime-l-1604/msg00005.html)) for that deal.

This means, the panama papers generate a lot of media attention, and probably already paid off for the *Süddeutsche Zeitung* but it wont have much impact as long as the full papers are not completely published at all.

WikiLeaks already asked the *rhetoric* question [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/wikileaks/status/716772373408718849), if they should release the full papers. Which is a rhetoric question trying to make people aware that *nothing* was leaked yet. And Wikileaks can't leak anything at all, since the 'whistleblower' decided not to leak to the public but to sell to the media. That's a huge difference.

#### No data

So far, the *SZ* never leaked any documents (0). Instead, the guardian leaked a total of 2 documents.

**Out of the roughly 11,500,000 documents, only [152 are available currently on document cloud](https://www.documentcloud.org/public/search/Source:%20%22Internal%20documents%20from%20Mossack%20Fonseca%20%28Panama%20Papers%29%22/p2)**. Not much more was really leaked so far.

To answer the question more directly, the **Panama Papers** including 11.5 million documents and 2.6 TiB in size **can not be downloaded** anywhere.

The best you can do is hand-picking the few released documents out there or wait until someone from inside the media company leaks the full dump.

Comment: Good answer. Part of it is personal opinion though and not in response to the question ("[...] it wont have much impact as long as [...]")

Answer (score 3):

It seems the media is not releasing it to the public yet.

There are some links floating around to a similar (but smaller) 2013 leak, but that is not the one that was released today.

<s>http://www.thereportertimes.com/panama-papers-icij-offshore-leaks-database-documents/23489/</s>

https://archive.org/download/OffshoreLeaksDatabase

This appears to have the high-level data, though no details about the people involved.
http://pastebin.com/pern5JRF

Answer (score 3):

Still waiting for the entire cache, but The Sunday Times has released a [list with 37,000 names](http://features.thesundaytimes.co.uk/web/public/2016/04/10/index.html) (10 April 2016).

> Search our database of 37,000 names linked to Mossack Fonseca companies in the tax haven of Panama

**Direct Link to [CSV download](https://cdn.rawgit.com/times/data/master/sunday_times_panama_data.zip)** (4.4 MB zipped)